# How can I upload more than one file with vagrant file provisioning?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

In a Vagrant setup, I have to upload a couple of files from the host to the guest during the provisioning phase.

In https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/file.html I can see how to upload a single file, from a source to a destination, but how can I upload multiple files or a folder structure?

NOTE: I know I can do that using the shell provisioner, but in this particular case a set of file uploads would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would need a separate `config.vim.provision` section for each file. You can add multiple of those sections to your `Vagrantfile`, like this:

```rb
config.vm.provision :file do |file|
  file.source = "/etc/file1.txt"
  file.destination = "/tmp/1.txt"
end

config.vm.provision :file do |file|
  file.source = "/etc/file2.txt"
  file.destination = "/tmp/2.txt"
end
```

Output:

```
[default] Running provisioner: file...
[default] Running provisioner: file...
```

You see it is executing both provisioning actions. You can verify the file presence inside the virtual machine:

```
vagrant ssh -- ls -al /tmp/{1,2}.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 4 Aug 27 08:22 /tmp/1.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 4 Aug 27 08:22 /tmp/2.txt
```

Comment: Looks exactly what I was looking for... Any tip for entire folder structures?

Comment: @GiacomoTesio When you want to make a whole folder accessible, use [`config.vm.synced_folder`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/)

Comment: that's not what I need. For example I have a few files to be moved into /etc/apt/source.list.d/ from the host machine. I tried with tar in the shell provisioner (something like (cd root/ && tar cf - *) | (cd / && tar xf - --keep-old-files) ), but it doesn't works.

Comment: Then you need to iterate over the folder with ruby and create the `config.vm.provision` entries dynamically.

Answer (score 12):

Folder content uploads seem to work as well (I've only tried it with files, not nested folders):

```
config.vm.provision :file, source: '../folder', destination: "/tmp/folder"
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to be working just fine. Also with nested folders.

Comment: i had trouble with this. source:'../one/two', destination: '/destination' works as expected the first time, with all the files in /destination. Run vagrant provision again and you get all the files in /destination/two

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody else just needs a quick and dirty hack to copy a directory structure from the host to the guest, this is how I finally did it:

```rb
require 'pathname' # at the beginning of the Vagrantfile

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # more configuration here

  r = Pathname.new 'root'
  Dir.glob(File.join("root", File.join("**","*"))) do |f|
    if !File.directory?(f) then
      s = Pathname.new f
      t = s.relative_path_from r
      config.vm.provision "file" do |fp|
        fp.source = s.to_s
        fp.destination = "/tmp/root/" + t.to_s
      end
    end
  end

  # more configuration here

end
```

Thanks to [@hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25522221/412808) for getting me on [the right track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516462/how-can-i-upload-more-than-one-file-with-vagrant-file-provisioning/#comment39851168_25522221).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, cd to your vagrant then run

```
vagrant up
vagrant ssh

vagrant@yourvagrant: sudo chown -R testuser:testuser /var/www/ or whatever folder you want to upload your files
```

and in you Vagrantfile, add

```
# we create add script to upload folder to a vagrant guest from local file
config.vm.provision :file, source: '/wamp/www/ian_loans', destination:  "/var/www/solidbond"
```

just replace the file directory to your needs.Exit and 
and don't forget to run in your vagrant directory

```
vagrant provision
```

finally go to your Ubuntu directory and see if the file you want to upload is there.

```
vagrant@yourvagrant: cd /var/your file directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use file provisioner, as others had mentioned but it's still worth noting that it's possible to use a synced folder functionality with type set to rsync: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html:

> Vagrant can use rsync as a mechanism to sync a folder to the guest
>   machine. This synced folder type is useful primarily in situations
>   where other synced folder mechanisms are not available, such as when
>   NFS or VirtualBox shared folders aren't available in the guest
>   machine.
>
> The rsync synced folder does a one-time one-way sync from the machine
>   running to the machine being started by Vagrant.

On the first `vagrant up` syncing happens before provisioners are executed. Sample configuration in Vagrantfile would look like this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "upload/", "/home/vagrant", type: "rsync"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little old but I'll throw another answer in here for entire directory structures for Windows users using PowerShell.

First, create a Powershell script that copies over an entire folder structure from a shared folder.

```
#Check if the directory you're copying already exists on the VM
$foldercheck = "path\to\folder\on\vm"
if (test-path $foldercheck)
{
    Write-Host "Folder 'path\to\folder\on\vm' already exists..."
}
else {
    #Create the new directory
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "path\to\folder\on\vm"

    #Copy over contents to the directory
    Copy-Item "\\VBOXSRV\<share_name>\path\to\folder\to\copy\*" -Destination "path\to\folder\on\vm" -recurse
}
```

Then, configure your Vagrantfile to automount a sharedfolder, copy over PowerShell scripts, and then run them in the order specified.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        # Other settings
        # ...
        # Add shared folders
        vb.customize ["sharedfolder", "add", :id, "--name", "<share_name>", "--hostpath", "path/to/host/folder/location", "--automount"]
    end
    # =================================================================
    # PROVISIONING
    # =================================================================
    # Load up the files to the Guest environment for use by PowerShell
    config.vm.provision "file", source: "path/to/provisioning/files/powershellfile.ps1", destination: "path/to/temporary/location/powershellfile.ps1"
    # Rinse/repeat for additional provisioning files

    # Now provision files in the order they are specified
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "path/to/temporary/location/powershellfile.ps1"
    # Rinse/repeat to run PowerShell scripts
end
```