# vagrant-Git repository

Tags: github, vagrant

I'm using vagrant to clone my git repository. I deleted my repository from GitHub my git account. now trying to clone a repository couldn't error message is destination path already exist. how do I delete this already existing path and start afresh?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25528259/6309), you can:

- test if a [folder exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085260/6309) (`File.directory?(directory)`)
- delete it, using `FileUtils.rmdir(disks_directory)` (as used in this [Vagrant script](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2021/05/10/how-to-define-multiple-disks-inside-vagrant-using-virtualbox-provider/))